# Zombie objects after std::move

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I'm confused about the state of an object *after* it's been moved using C++0x move semantics.  My understanding is that once an object has been moved, it's still a valid object, but its internal state has been altered so that when its destructor is called, no resources are deallocated.

But if my understanding is correct, the destructor of a moved object *should* still be called.

But, that doesn't happen when I perform a simple test:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo()  
    {
        s = new char[100]; 
        cout << "Constructor called!" << endl;  
    }

    Foo(Foo&& f) 
    {
        s = f.s;
        f.s = 0;
    }

    ~Foo() 
    { 
        cout << "Destructor called!" << endl;   
        delete[] s; // okay if s is NULL
    }

    void dosomething() { cout << "Doing something..." << endl; }

    char* s;
};

void work(Foo&& f2)
{
    f2.dosomething();
}

int main()
{
    Foo f1;
    work(std::move(f1));
}
```

This output:

```
Constructor called!
Doing something...
Destructor called!
```

Notice the destructor is only called once.  This shows that my understanding here is off.  Why wasn't the destructor called twice?  Here's my interpretation of what *should* have happened:

1. `Foo f1` is constructed.
2. `Foo f1` is passed to `work`, which
   takes an rvalue `f2`.
3. The move constructor of `Foo` is
   called, moving all resources in `f1`
   to `f2`.
4. Now `f2`'s destructor is called,
   releasing all resources.
5. Now `f1`'s destructor is called,
   which doesn't actually do anything
   since all resources were transferred
   to `f2`.  Still, the destructor is
   called nonetheless.

But since only one destructor is called, either step 4 or step 5 isn't happening.  I did a backtrace from the destructor to see where it was being invoked from, and it's being invoked from step 5.  So why isn't `f2`'s destructor also called?

**EDIT:** Okay, I modified this so it's actually managing a resource.  (An internal memory buffer.)  Still, I get the same behavior where the destructor is only called once.

Comment: which compiler are you testing on?

Comment: gcc 4.3 .........................

Comment: In that case it may be worth noting that it's written against a much older version of the C++0x draft. And move semantics have been changed quite a bit since then. For example, I believe a newer compiler would have rejected your code entirely before you added the `std::move`. It wouldn't be able to call `work` because the argument was effectively a lvalue reference because it was named.

Comment: @jalf, okay.  But do you agree with me that, as of the current C++0x draft, the destructor should be called twice here?

Comment: @Channel72: assuming the move isn't optimized away, yes.

Comment: *Related:* [How can moved objects be used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872521/how-can-moved-objects-be-used)

Comment: @jalf The updated code compiles correctly, and does *not* call the move constructor, with GCC 4.9.

Comment: I made some simple modifications of this code that led to a segfault and some further confusion on my part: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30466949/1858225

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit** *(New and correct answer)*
Sorry, looking closer at the code, it seems the answer is much simpler:
you never invoke the move constructor. You never actually move the object. You just pass a rvalue reference to the `work` function, which calls a member function *on that reference*, which still points back to the original object.

**Original answer, saved for posterity**

In order to actually perform the move, you have to have something like `Foo f3(std::move(f2));` inside `work`. Then you can call your member function on `f3` which is a new object, created by moving from `f`

As far as I can see, you don't get move semantics at all. You're just seeing plain old copy elision.

for the move to happen, you have to use `std::move` (or specifically, the argument being passed to the constructor has to be an unnamed/temporary) rvalue reference, such as the one that is returned from `std::move`). Otherwise it is treated as a plain old-fashioned lvalue reference, and then a copy *should* happen, but as usual, the compiler is allowed to optimize it away, leaving you with one object being constructed, and one object being destroyed.

Anyway, even with move semantics, there's no reason why the compiler shouldn't do the same thing: just optimize the move, just like it'd have optimized away the copy. A move is cheap, but it's still cheaper to just construct the object where you need it, rather than constructing one, and then moving it into another location and calling the destructor on the first one.

It's also worth noting that you're using a relatively old compiler, and earlier versions of the spec were very unclear on what should happen with these "zombie objects". So it is possible that GCC 4.3 just doesn't call the destructor. I believe it's only the last revision, or maybe the one before it, that explicitly requires the destructor to be called

Comment: Okay, I added an explicit call to `std::move`, just to be certain I'm really passing an rvalue.  But it doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to. As far as I know, the compiler is allowed to perform copy elision (or move elision, I guess) on rvalue references as well: in your simple test case, it can just construct the object in place, rather than constructing one and then moving it.

Comment: Hmm...okay, I edited the code so that `Foo` now actually manages a resource.  It allocates a buffer and transfers ownership of the buffer in the move constructor.  However, the destructor is still only called once.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: @Chanel72: as far as I can see, there's still nothing preventing the compiler from just optimizing away the move. Why does it need the original object at all? You're just moving away from it immediately.

Comment: @Chanel72: try to compile with `-S`, you will see what is actually being done (in assembler).

Comment: If I were you, I'd define every type of constructor (including the copy ctor which atm is compiler-generated) to write some output, so you can see exactly how many times each constructor is called.

Comment: Oh, also check my edit. Looks like the answer is much simpler

Comment: You should really move the edit to the top.  It's the issue that solves the question.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that the compiler may optimize out the unneeded construction/destruction, effectively making only one object exist. This is especially true for rvalue references (which were invented exactly for this purpose).

I think you are wrong in your interpretation of what happens. The move constructor is not called: if the value is not a temporary, the rvalue reference behaves as a normal reference.

Maybe [this article](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/rvalue.html) will bring more information about rvalue reference semantics.

Comment: Even if I don't compile with any optimization flags?

Comment: @Channel72: the C++ standard doesn't care about optimization flags. An optimization is either legal (it respects the semantics of C++), or it isn't. And as long as it is legal, the compiler can apply it whenever it likes, as far as the C++ standard is concerned. Of course, if it isn't legal, it should *never* be applied. The compiler usually performs several small optimizations (RVO, for example, and on some compilers, NRVO as well) even with optimizations disabled. It probably also performs copy elision, which would explain your results

Comment: I think there is no copying at all, as you don't actually have any temporary objects in your code.

Comment: yeah... I wonder why I didn't see that until now. You never actually ask for a move, you just pass references around. The fact that they're rvalue references instead of lvalue ones doesn't change that they're still references, not new objects.