# Why doesn't this RAII move-only type properly emulate `std::unique_ptr`?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, unique-ptr

I took the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4082065/1858225) and edited it to produce a segfault by explicitly calling the destructor of one of the move-constructed objects:

```
using namespace std;

struct Foo
{
    Foo()  
    {
        s = new char[100]; 
        cout << "Constructor called!" << endl;  
    }

    Foo(const Foo& f) = delete;

    Foo(Foo&& f) :
      s{f.s}
    {
        cout << "Move ctor called!" << endl;   
        f.s = nullptr;
    }

    ~Foo() 
    { 
        cout << "Destructor called!" << endl;   
        cout << "s null? " << (s == nullptr) << endl;
        delete[] s; // okay if s is NULL
    }

    char* s;
};

void work(Foo&& f2)
{
    cout << "About to create f3..." << endl;
    Foo f3(move(f2));
    // f3.~Foo();
}

int main()
{
    Foo f1;
    work(move(f1));
}
```

Compiling and running this code (with G++ 4.9) produces the following output:

```
Constructor called!
About to create f3...
Move ctor called!
Destructor called!
s null? 0
Destructor called!
s null? 0
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: double free or corruption (!prev): 0x0916a060 ***
```

Note that when the destructor is not explicitly called, no double-free error occurs.

Now, when I change the type of `s` to `unique_ptr<char[]>` and remove the `delete[] s` in `~Foo()` and `f.s = nullptr` in `Foo(Foo&&)` (see full code below), I do *not* get a double-free error:

```
Constructor called!
About to create f3...
Move ctor called!
Destructor called!
s null? 0
Destructor called!
s null? 1
Destructor called!
s null? 1
```

What is going on here? Why can the moved-to object be explicitly deleted when its data member is a `unique_ptr`, but not when the invalidation of the moved-from object is handled manually in `Foo(Foo&&)`? Since the move-constructor *is* called when `f3` is created (as shown by the "Move ctor called!" line), why does the first destructor call (presumably for `f3`) state that `s` is *not* null? If the answer is simply that `f3` and `f2` are somehow actually the same object due to an optimization, what is `unique_ptr` doing that's preventing the same problem from happening with that implementation?

---

**EDIT:** As requested, the full code using `unique_ptr`:

```
using namespace std;

 struct Foo
{
    Foo() :
      s{new char[100]}
    {
        cout << "Constructor called!" << endl;  
    }

    Foo(const Foo& f) = delete;

    Foo(Foo&& f) :
      s{move(f.s)}
    {
        cout << "Move ctor called!" << endl;   
    }

    ~Foo() 
    { 
        cout << "Destructor called!" << endl;   
        cout << "s null? " << (s == nullptr) << endl;
    }

    unique_ptr<char[]> s;
};

void work(Foo&& f2)
{
    cout << "About to create f3..." << endl;
    Foo f3(move(f2));
    f3.~Foo();
}

int main()
{
    Foo f1;
    work(move(f1));
}
```

I have double-checked that this produces the output copied above.

**EDIT2:** Actually, using Coliru (see T.C.'s link below), this exact code *does* produce a double-deletion error.

Comment: Note: even though primitive types such as `char[]` don't have true move constructors, I did try using `s{move(f.s)}` instead of `s{f.s}` in the move-constructor, just to see if that might have something to do with the observed behavior; as expected, it made no difference.

Comment: Why would you explicitly call the the destructor? It makes no sense. Of course things get double deleted if you do that.

Comment: @PeterSW Precisely to test whether I have properly created a `unique_ptr`-like move-only type. As you can see, a well-designed move-only type is robust to usage like this.

Comment: Post the full `unique_ptr` version please, since [I can't reproduce this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a334aaa94070457). Also, I would actually consider it a performance bug if `unique_ptr`'s destructor is written to tolerate double destruction.

Comment: Destroying the `unique_ptr` twice is invoking undefined behaviour. I'm not really sure we can learn much about correctness based on results from that.

Comment: @T.C. I have done so. I'm still not quite clear on why there's double destruction happening here, though; there are three named `Foo` objects, `f1`, `f2`, and `f3`, and three separate destructor calls. If the compiler is eliding out two move constructions, why is it still calling the corresponding destructors?

Comment: I think the attempted destruction order is something like: `f3` from explicit call, `f2` from going out of scope, `f3` from going out of scope, `f1` from going out of scope.

Comment: Looks like [this depends on the optimizer settings](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb834622f4bfc59a). Classic UB.

Comment: @PeterSW Augh, yes, of course. I think I meant to ensure that the moved-from `f2` could be explicitly deleted without error, which does seem to be the case: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9af11a7643c65c2  I used `unique_ptr` as a sanity-check to ensure that a "properly-implemented" move-only class behaved in the way I expected, and didn't realize I was running into UB due to deleting the object that had been moved _to_.

Comment: I'm surprised nobody else is mentioning it, but I think your class violates the rule of three: you didn't handle copy assignment.  I'm not 100% sure though, since you did delete the copy constructor.

Comment: @MooingDuck I was mostly interested in constructor-call behavior and construction-elision (as noted, the code is only slightly modified from the code in another question). There's no way to accidentally call an assignment operator without actually writing an assignment statement using `=`, is there?

Comment: @KyleStrand: In general, yes there are ways.  However, your code doesn't trigger any of them.  You're right that the rule-of-three violation isn't causing your bug, and is unrelated to the question, but it's still _a_ bug to fix.

Comment: @MooingDuck Well, all I'm trying to do here is understand move-construction behavior; this isn't going to become production code, even though it will inform how I think about and write production code.

Comment: "As you can see, a well-designed move-only type is robust to usage like this." it is never, ever safe to delete a moved-from type an extra time.  Explicitly calling the destructor should be paired with explicitly calling placement new on the location of the object (either before, or after -- and after is always suspect!)  Much like `t = new T(args...)` is paired with `delete t;`, `t->~T();` is paired with `T* t = new(&location) T(args...);`.

Comment: @PeterSW `f2` is a reference. There's nothing to destroy.

Comment: @Yakk I think I understand how the statement "it is never, ever safe to delete a moved-from type an extra time" is in accordance with the fact that double-deletion is always technically UB, but I'm not quite sure I understand how, say, `unique_ptr` could ever cause bad behavior when moved-from and *then* double-deleted: move-constructing a `unique_ptr` causes the moved-*from* pointer value to be set to `nullptr`, and the `unique_ptr` destructor just deletes the pointer value (right?), and it's always safe to delete `nullptr`.

Comment: Even in the case above, it appears that I would not have run into a seg-fault if I had attempted to explicitly delete the moved-from `f2` instead of the moved-to `f3`.

Comment: @T.C. yep, my mistake. Thanks for pointing it out. So it's `f3` from explicit call, `f3` from going out of scope, `f1` from going out of scope.

Comment: @KyleStrand the compiler is free to detect your double deletion, and inject a `rm -rf /`. The compiler is free to detect your double deletion, determine it is UB, and eliminate the destructions. Or the entire branch that leads to the UB, because if a branch leads to UB, not running the entire branch is a clear optimization (standard compliant code that as-if identical to your code). You laugh, but that is what gcc will do if it detects a branch that requires signed integer overflow (even on hardware that would "actually" just do a 2s complement overflow).

Comment: @Yakk I realize that "undefined" means that a malicious compiler author could do something malicious and still technically conform to the standard, but that's not really what I'm trying to ask. Optimizing away UB branches seems like a good example, though. With that said, we're looking at double *destruction* here, not double *deletion*, and it's my understanding that since the destructor is just a method, explicitly calling it twice is *not* inherently undefined behavior--right?--and we're only seeing it in this case because the destructor happens to *perform* a deletion.

Comment: So in the case of a moved-from `unique_ptr` being destroyed twice, it still seems to me that *no* "deletions" happen, because a moved-from `unique_ptr` will have nothing in it to delete (not counting the "deletion" of the `nullptr` member).

Comment: @Yakk Er, nevermind, you're right, double-destruction is also UB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any class with a non-trivial destructor, destroying it twice is undefined behavior by core language rule:

[basic.life]/p1:

> The lifetime of an object of type `T` ends when:
>
> - if `T` is a class type with a non-trivial destructor (12.4), the destructor call starts, or
> - the storage which the object occupies is reused or released.

[class.dtor]/p15:

> the behavior is undefined if the destructor is invoked for an object
>   whose lifetime has ended (3.8)

Your code destroys `f3` twice, once by explicit destructor call and once by leaving the scope, so it has undefined behavior.

It happens that both libstdc++ and libc++'s `unique_ptr` destructor will assign a null pointer to the stored pointer (libc++ calls `reset()`; libstdc++ does it manually). This is not required by the standard, and is arguably a performance bug in something that's meant to be an zero-overhead wrapper over raw pointers. As a result, your code "works" in `-O0`.

g++ at `-O2`, however, is able to see that the assignment in the destructor cannot possibly be observed by a well-defined program, so it optimizes away the assignment, causing a double delete.

Answer (score 3):

If you call destructor explicitely, it will be called second time implicitely when `f3` goes out of scope. This creates UB and that is why your class crashes.

You can work-around the crash in `delete` by resetting `s` to `nullptr` in the destructor (so that second time it is `nullptr`) but the UB in calling destructor twice will be still there.