# State of object after std::move construction

Tags: c++11, move-semantics

Is it legal/proper c++0x to leave an object moved for the purpose of move-construction in a state that can only be destroyed? For instance:

```
class move_constructible {...};

int main()
{
    move_constructible x;
    move_constructible y(std::move(x));
    // From now on, x can only be destroyed. Any other method will result
    // in a fatal error.
}
```

For the record, I'm trying to wrap in a c++ class a c struct with a pointer member which is always supposed to be pointing to some allocated memory area. All the c library API relies on this assumption. But this requirement prevents to write a truly cheap move constructor, since in order for x to remain a valid object after the move it will need its own allocated memory area. I've written the destructor in such a way that it will first check for NULL pointer before calling the corresponding cleanup function from the c API, so that at least the struct can be safely destroyed after the move.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do with a moved-from object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027523/what-can-i-do-with-a-moved-from-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the language allows this. In fact it was one of the purposes of move semantics. It is however your responsibility to ensure that no other methods get called and/or provide proper diagnostics. Note, usually you can also use at least the assignment operator to "revive" your variable, such as in the classical example of swapping two values.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872521/how-can-moved-objects-be-used)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Indeed, the requirements mentioned in that link sound reasonable and easily implementable. Cheers.