# What happens to the moved-from object after std::move() is called?

Tags: c++

I have read that we should make sure that there are no users of moved-from object before moving it. I want to know why is that so ? 
Is the moved-from object destroyed after std::move() is called ? if not, What happens to the moved-from object after std::move() is called ?

Comment: Also duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/7930105/1870232

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how the result of `std::move()` is used. `move` itself does not do anything to the object.

Comment: Fair point. The statement `std::move(std::string("Hello"));` is legal, but does not move anything.

Answer (score 0):

The object is not destroyed, but it's in a state where the only thing still possible is to destroy it.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be in a state that is safe to destruct, but, AFAIK, it does not have to be usable for anything else.