# If I move a local object into a function, will it still be valid afterward?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

So, this provides the intended output:

```
void f(std::string&& s)
{
   s += " plus extra";
}

int main(void)
{
   std::string str = "A string";
   f( std::move(str) );
   std::cout << str << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

> > A string plus extra

That is, it works when I run it on Ideone, but is it UB?  Adding extra string initializations before and after the call to `f` didn't change anything.

Comment: Yes it will still be valid but what it contains is *undefined*. The only methods you should call on the string after *moving* from it are to replace its contents with something new. For example `str.clear();`.

Comment: Related: [What can I do with a moved-from object?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7027523/3425536)

Comment: The string isn't moved, an rvalue reference is sent and the ownership isn't took away. This code is completely valid. No UB is involved here and no _undefined content_, or whatever that means, is involved here.

Comment: That example doesn't actually move the string btw.

Comment: It doesn't have to, but in general, when I see a function that accepts an rvalue reference, I expect it to consume the object.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Thank you, but how do you know the string isn't moved?  Is this because `s` is never assigned to anything within the function body?

Comment: Yes, because you directly receive the reference and you do not make any operation that would end up invalidating the string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code is valid, because there no actual moving is performed. Here is how you could make it invalid:

```
string f(std::string&& s) {
    std::string res(std::move(s));
    res += " plus extra";
    return res;
}
```

The state of `str` after this call would be valid, but unspecified. This means that you could still assign a new value to `str` to put it back into a valid state, but you wouldn't be able to output it without invoking unspecified behavior ([demo](http://ideone.com/F3RvNP)). See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7930105/335858) for specifics on the moved-from state.

Answer (score 18):

It is valid, not UB.

It is also horribly obfuscated code.  `std::move(s)` is nothing but a cast to rvalue.  By itself it does not actually generate *any* code at all.  Its only purpose is to turn an lvalue into an rvalue so that client code can overload on lvalue/rvalue expressions (of `string` in this case).

You should pass by lvalue-reference for this case:

```
void f(std::string& s)
{
   s += " plus extra";
}
...
f( str );
```

Or alternatively, pass by value and return a new string:

```
std::string f(std::string s)
{
   s += " plus extra";
   return s;
}
...
str = f( std::move(str) );
```

Answer (score 10):

**`std::move` doesn't move anything.** It indicates that an object may be "*moved from*", by casting its argument to an *rvalue*.

Your code is valid and there is no move operation performed.

You would get the behavior where the state of `str` is unspecified after calling `f()`, if you *move-construct* another string object from `s`. The move-constructor performs the actual move operation.

Example:

```
std::vector<std::string> sv;

void f(std::string&& s)
{
    s += " plus extra";
    sv.push_back(std::move(s));         // move s (str) into a new object
}

int main(void)
{
   std::string str = "A string";
   f(std::move(str));                 
   std::cout << str << std::endl;       // output: empty string
   std::cout << sv.back() << std::endl; // output: "A string plus extra"

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Might also want to mention copy elision, and how `&&` is largely unnecessary outside move constructors/move assignment operators.

Answer (score 3):

`std::move` is just casting your object to an rvalue reference. Since your function takes the reference and just do something with it, no ownership is taken here, so your string is still in a valid state and can be used safely.

I would not recommend using this in your code because it's misleading, as a lot of people would consider your string as invalid, because taking ownership is the primary use of rvalue reference, hence `std::move`.

If you're really need to call this function this way, I would recommend writing this:

```
std::string myString{"a string"};

// leave a comment here to explain what you are doing.
f(static_cast<std::string&&>(myString));
```

However, please note that your example would be really different if the function `f` took value instead of a reference. In that case, calling it with both `std::move` or `static_cast` would invalidate the string.