# What exactly is required of an xvalue that has been moved from?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What constitutes a valid state for a “moved from” object in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095048/what-constitutes-a-valid-state-for-a-moved-from-object-in-c11)

Consider something like this:

```
class Foo {};  
std::vector<Foo> v( 5 );
```

Is it legal to do something like:

```
v.front() = std::move( v.back() );
```

provided that I do something like this afterwards:

```
v.pop_back();
```

More precisely I want to know what is required for an xvalue that has undergone `std::move()` semantics.
I know it needs to be destructible (obviously). But anything else? Suppose I would call `std::vector::insert()` or some other function, that may do some copying/moving of the `std::move()`ed value behind the scenes.
Is that still legal?

In my real case I have `std::vector<std::vector<Foo>>` and do stuff with that.
But I don't know if it is legal to `std::move()` from a `std::vector` that is still used by the outer `std::vector`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is valid:  you can always destroy a moved-from object.  (I cannot find where--or whether--this is specified in the C++ language standard, but if a moved-from object could not be destroyed, I'm sure we'd all consider that a bug.)  Since your code only destroys the moved-from object, your code is fine.

The Standard Library imposes additional requirements on the state of a moved-from object and any type with which a Standard Library component is instantiated must follow these additional rules.  The gist is that move and copy operations that are valid on non-moved-from objects of a type must also be valid for moved-from objects of the type.  So, for example, after moving the last element, you could assign that element a new value:  `v.back() = Foo();`.

Comment: Ok! Thank you :) Though I'd love to find that somewhere eithin the depths of the standard I believe you. It is what common sense should tell ;)

Comment: @iolo, See 17.3.26 [defns.valid] and 17.6.5.15 [lib.types.movedfrom]