# std::vector: contiguous data and copy/move

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, contiguous

I have two questions for the following code: **1)** Will the elements of `faces` be contiguous?
**2)** Does `std::vector` copy or move `Face f` when inserting it?

```
#include <vector>    
int main()
{
    struct Face {};
    std::vector<Face> faces;

    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    {
        Face f;

        faces.push_back (f);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're worried about it copying or moving it (it's a move in this particular case) - why not use `.emplace`?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Both `push_back` and `emplace_back` will use the copy constructor to create the object within the `std::vector` (in this example).

Comment: @nosid I meant - rather than create it outside the loop, emplace it in the loop. I'd love to hear why that would not be able to utilize move semantics though. I was under the impression gcc and clang would trivially do this (assuming a struct that isn't "empty")

Comment: FYI the existance of default move assignment operator & move constructor might [depend on your environment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819936/why-no-default-move-assignment-move-constructor)

Comment: If Face is a small, simple struct (easy to copy) don't worry about the extra copies.

Comment: @Scis I assumed since this is tagged C++11 then C++11 semantics apply.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: I do not understand what you mean by _outside the loop_ and _in the loop_. Regardless, `f` is an lvalue reference, and there the compiler can't use the move constructor for lvalue references -- neither for `push_back` nor for `emplace_back`. The only exception to this rule is the `return` statement.

Comment: Worth noting that they might not be contiguous in C++98.

Comment: @chris Not really. They were always supposed to be contiguous, and when it was discovered that the C++98 standard didn't say so explicitly, they added a paragraph to C++03 to ensure it was so. I don't think there was ever an implementation of std::vector that wasn't contiguous.

Comment: @RickYorgason, Yeah, probably not.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the standard § 23.3.6.1 Class template vector overview [vector.overview] :

> *The elements of a `vector` **are stored contiguously**, meaning that if `v` is a `vector<T, Allocator>` where `T` is some type other than `bool`, then it obeys the identity `&v[n] == &v[0] + n for all 0 <= n < v.size()`.*

As far as it concerns your second question in prior C++11 compilers `push_back` would copy the object you push back.

After C++11  it depends because `push_back` has two overloads, one that takes an `lvalue` reference and another one that takes an `rvalue` reference.

In your case It will be copied because you are passing the object as an `lvalue`. To ensure movement of the object you could use `std::move()`.

```
faces.push_back(std::move(f));
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's _it will be copied_ and not _it might be copied_ here? Is a compiler performing a move in this particular case violating the spec?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum If you are referring to copy elision, If I remember correctly, this is not one of the cases that could be applied. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca6136f941af40eb

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: There can be no move because it is neither cast to an rvalue reference, nor returned as an lvalue nor starts out as an unnamed unbound object. There can be no copy ellision either, 40two is right about that.

Comment: Uhm, has the "as if" rule been removed from recent versions of the standard?

Comment: @NicolaMusatti No the "as if" rule still holds (please see § 1.9/5 Program execution [intro.execution]). Overload resolution rules are the ones to blame :).

Comment: @40two So in this case moving instead of copying is a valid optimization, as it can be easily proved that f is not used after the push_back(). There aren't any guarantees that your compiler will do it, though.

Comment: `There aren't any guarantees that your compiler will do it, though.`: In statement `faces.push_back(std::move(f));` `f` will be effectively moved. `f` after being moved is going to be placed in a valid but unspecified state (please see *17.6.5.15 Moved-from state of library types                                 [lib.types.movedfrom]*). Also please read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12095473/2352671