# Usage of objects that have been moved from

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

The following code works on my computer, but is this guaranteed to work by the C++ standard?

```
void do_stuff(std::string);
std::string s;

while(std::cin >> s){
    do_stuff(std::move(s));
}
```

From my understanding of the standard, objects that are moved *from* are left in a valid but unspecified state, and are only worthy of destruction.  Hence, the code isn't guaranteed to work.

As an extension, is the following valid, given the knowledge of the `Notification` class and the fact that `get_notification` overwrites the member `details`?

```
struct Notification{
    string details;
};

string get_string();
void do_more_stuff(Notification);
void get_notification(Notification& n){
    n.details = get_string();
}

Notification n;

while(get_notification(n)){
    do_more_stuff(std::move(n));
}
```

Comment: I think that it depends on the type. `std::string` says _Move constructor. Constructs the string with the contents of other using move semantics. other is left in valid, but unspecified state._ `basic_stream_socket::operator=` (boost asio) on the other hand says _Following the move, the moved-from object is in the same state as if constructed using the basic_stream_socket(io_service&) constructor._ , which means that you can continue to use the moved-from object in a call to e.g. `accept`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What constitutes a valid state for a "moved from" object in C++11?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095048/what-constitutes-a-valid-state-for-a-moved-from-object-in-c11)

Comment: How could "valid" mean "only worthy of destruction"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> From my understanding of the standard, objects that are moved from are left in a valid but unspecified state,

This part is true.

> and are only worthy of destruction

This part is not true. There *are* things you can do with an object that was moved from: any operation that does not have a precondition. For instance, `clear()` has no preconditions on the string, so you can `clear()` a moved-from string. At that point, you are in a specified state. Similarly, `erase()` has no preconditions.

`operator>>` is another operation that has no preconditions (indeed, it is specified to call `erase()`). So this code:

```
while(std::cin >> s){
    do_stuff(std::move(s));
}
```

is actually fine.

Comment: I think you *can* perform operations with precondition (i.e. read state from object): it's not particularly useful as the outcome is unknown, but it should be guaranteed not to crash. For example, you can `std::cout << s` as well, but characters that end up on screen are not specified, it may be original string, empty string or even (U+1F4A9) 'PILE OF POO'. All of those are valid possible outcomes.

Comment: @el.pescado Performing operations with preconditons would be undefined behavior. It is not guaranteed not to crash.

Comment: I thought about it and I think you're right. I confused "querying state" with "having preconditions".