# C++: valid but unspecified state. What does this mean?

Tags: c++, move

I have been trying to understand std::move. [This](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/move/) doc describes it nicely. But it says in the example section "..... while bar loses its value, and now is in a valid but unspecified state .....". Lots of other docs also use this terminology in the same context. Also, I found lots of answers on stackoverflow related to it. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095048/what-constitutes-a-valid-state-for-a-moved-from-object-in-c11) is an exactly same question. But it does not talk about "What being unspecified means?"

So my questions are?

What does being valid but unspecified means?

What will be its effect on a pointer variable (`ClassA* ptr`)?

And what will be the effects on the object being pointed by the variable?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that moving from a raw pointer is the same as copying from it.  The pointer is not changed.

Comment: @CoryKramer I did read answers to the question you are pointing. But no one there talks about what being unspecified means.

Comment: @aschepler Thanks. You mean it's same as copying the value of the pointer variable. Right? So it will have no effect on the object, it is pointing to. Right?

Comment: @CoryKramer, I came from that above-mentioned "What can I do with a moved-from object?" ("duplicate") question _exactly_ because that one has only referred to, and quoted, and "speculated" about that "unspecified but valid", instead of ever defining it properly.