# Ok to use std::getline() with a moved-from std::string?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, c++14, c++17

Is it safe and well-defined for the second argument to [`std::getline(std::istream&, std::string&)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to be an lvalue referring to a moved-from [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), and, if so, is that string restored from its moved-from state, so methods such as [`pop_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/pop_back) can be safely invoked?

Put more simply, does writing to a string with `getline()` have equivalent semantics to assigning to that string?

Or more concretely, is the following (somewhat contrived) snippet well-defined and correct?

```cpp
std::ifstream f("foo.txt");

std::vector<std::string> lines;

for (std::string s; std::getline(f, s); lines.push_back(std::move(s)))
        if (!s.empty() && s.back() == '\r')
                s.pop_back();
```

Optimized (`-march=native -O3`) builds of this snippet with `g++` and `clang++` appear to work as expected, but that is of course no guarantee.

I'd like to know if this is relying only on well-defined behavior according to the semantics of `getline()` in the C++11 standard, or, if not, if it's well-defined by a later edition of the standard, or, if not, if it's at least explicitly defined by any/all of the major implementations (G++, Clang++, Visual C++, Intel C++ Compiler).

NB: This is ***not*** a duplicate of previous questions asking whether it's safe to assign to a moved-from object (yes, if it's a trivial or STL type) because `getline()` is not the assignment operator.

Comment: If you're not sure, how about changing it so that you `emplace_back()` a new string and then call `std::getline(f, lines.back())` instead?

Comment: This might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12095473/969365 excerpt: _The object being in a 'valid' state means that all the requirements the standard specifies for the type still hold true. That means you can use any operation on a moved-from, standard library type for which the preconditions hold true._ If it is possible to use any operation on a moved-from standard library type, then std::getline should be safe to use as well.

Comment: @SirGuy That's my fallback, but AFAICT it's hard to do in a non-ugly way in a loop. Safety trumps aesthetics, of course.

Comment: @gurka I *think* my code is OK for that reason, but it's unclear whether `getline()` is guaranteed only to invoke methods for which a moved-from string satisfies the preconditions.

Answer (score 9):

Your code is safe, but only because you are checking if the `getline` successfully stored something in `s`.  If the sentry internal to `getline` failed to initialize, then nothing would be assigned to `s` and it would be left in the valid-but-unspecified state.  As long as `getline` succeeds in setting `s` to a known state, you're good.

And the very first thing `getline` does after successful sentry construction is set `s` to a zero size (a known state).

More details below in GManNickG's comment.

Comment: Beat me to it. In more detail, `getline` is specified to call `str.erase()`; if you look at the requirements for that, you will find it just requires `pos <= size()` which is trivially true because `pos` is 0 and `size()` is unsigned. (Also, `size()` has no preconditions.) So `getline` can safely do this on a moved-from string.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it safe and well-defined for the second argument to `std::getline(std::istream&, std::string&)` to be an lvalue referring to a moved-from `std::string`

Yes. Although it the moved-from string is left unspecified by the standard according to [[string.cons]p2](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.cons#2):

> [...]. In the second form, `str` is left in a valid state with an unspecified value.

The string is still in a valid state, it is just unspecified, i.e. you can't know which state it is in (in may be filled with some random characters). You can still to pass it to `std::getline`, because the standard says in [[string.io]p1](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.io#1) that `str.erase()` is called on the string, which empties it:

> [...] calls `str.erase()` [...]

(if the stream is valid, but I'll assume that is in your case).

No matter what the unspecified state of the string is, it is emptied at the start of `std::getline`, so it doesn't matter what state it is in.

Comment: "For example, std::string moved from state is just an empty string, nothing special." Is this guaranteed? Because this is more or less his question. After having moved from std::string it is valid but in a unspecified state. And the question is; is it OK to use a `std::string` which is "valid but in an _unspecified_ state" when using `std::getline`?

Comment: The move constructor for a basic_string leaves the source "in a valid state with an unspecified value." This is different from guaranteeing it's an empty string.

Comment: @gurka Ah I get it. It is not directly guaranteed, but this is what most implementations would do.

Comment: @Rakete1111 I think most implementations switched or will switch to SSO and will not nullify zero short strings

Answer (score 1):

A move assignment or move c'tor should always leave the moved object in a valid state.

In case of a std::string, when you `std::move` it, it stays a valid but unspecified string. From libc++'s source:

```
// __str is a valid, but unspecified string. 
basic_string(basic_string&& __str) noexcept
  : _M_dataplus(_M_local_data(), std::move(__str._M_get_allocator()))
```

And since `getline()` only appends chars to the string, as long as it succeeds, the output will be as expected. From [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/):

> Note that any content in str before the call is replaced by the newly extracted sequence.
>
> Each extracted character is appended to the string as if its member push_back was called.

Comment: This is all true, but doesn't answer the question of if `getline` does operations that require a more-specified string than fully unspecified.

Comment: @GManNickG, added explanation for exactly that