# How to use C++11 std::move semantics. I tried writing code, the output I get is some thing different

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;
int function(int &&p)
{
    cout<<"function:"<<p<<endl;

    return 0;
}
int main()
{

    int a =10;
    function(std::move(a));
    cout<<"main:"<<a<<endl;


    return 0;
}
```

The output I get is as below.

```
function:10
main:10
```

But shouldn't it be as below?

```
function:10
main:
```

Comment: Read this http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html

Comment: moveing a fundamental type would yield a copy

Comment: Can you suggest how my code to change to make output main:

Comment: there's no way to make `cout << a` print nothing, move or no move

Comment: A move constructor is supposed to leave a moved-from object in a [valid but unspecified state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095048/what-constitutes-a-valid-state-for-a-moved-from-object-in-c11).  What that is varies between types, but as a rule of thumb I just don't use a moved-from variable except to completely reassign it in some way (if at all), unless its move constructor gives me other guarantees (e.g. that of `std::vector`).

Comment: Hopefully, move semantic isn't an explicit destructor call. It doesn't undeclare an object, as there is no such thing as an undeclaration. It doesn't change the scope of a name or reduces the lifetime of an object.

Answer (score 4):

The `std::move` technically doesn't *move* anything, it just gives you an rvalue reference. The actual semantics of moving something only happen because this causes overload resolution to call different functions, so:

```
std::vector<int> a{1, 2, 3};
std::vector<int> b{std::move(a)};
```

This is equivalent to:

```
std::vector<int> a{1, 2, 3};
std::vector<int> b{static_cast<std::vector<int>&&>(a)};
```

Again, there's nothing special about the rvalue reference `&&` that makes it "move" things, all the move semantics are in the `std::vector` constructor. The `int` type doesn't have any special move semantics, so it doesn't do that.

This makes sense. For a `std::vector`, moving the vector and zeroing the original is cheaper than a copy. For an `int`, zeroing the original is actually *more expensive* than just copying it--you have to copy the value anyway, so there is no point in doing extra work to throw away the original.

Comment: IN the code snippet provided, if I try to access the values of vector a, what will the size of a be and what will the contents of a be?

Comment: See the documentation for the `std::vector` constructor. "After the move, other is guaranteed to be empty()." http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector

Comment: @arjunjawalkar: I was unable to substantiate this claim using the C++ standard, there's a longer discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730689/is-a-moved-from-vector-always-empty In general, I would consider it a style error to use an object after moving from it, unless it is reinitialized somehow.

Answer (score 2):

> But shouldn't it be as below?

No it should not.

---

#### Theory

1) [`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move):

> `std::move` produces an *xvalue* expression that identifies its argument
>   t. It is **exactly equivalent to a static_cast to an rvalue reference**
>   type.

2) [Rvalue references](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference):

> Rvalue references can be used to extend the lifetimes of temporary objects 
>   (note, ***lvalue*** **references to const can extend the lifetimes of
>   temporary objects too**, but **they are not modifiable** through them):

**Conclusion:**
since `a` is not a temporary, your code is essentially **equivalent to** passing `a` as **a reference**.

---

**Side note:**
in standard library

> Unless otherwise specified, all standard library objects that have
>   been moved from are placed in a valid but unspecified state.