# What does the author mean by "leave the object in an assignable state"?

Tags: c++, move, move-assignment-operator

The following is a snippet right at the end of [this article](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_04.html) by Mr. Thomas Becker:

```
X& X::operator=(X&& rhs)
{

  // Perform a cleanup that takes care of at least those parts of the
  // destructor that have side effects. Be sure to leave the object
  // in a destructible and **assignable state**.

  // Move semantics: exchange content between this and rhs

  return *this;
}
```

What does the author mean by "leave the object in an assignable state" above?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095048/what-constitutes-a-valid-state-for-a-moved-from-object-in-c11

Comment: In short, assigning to the object should not cause undefined behavior, and the object should assume the assigned value. i.e. `something = std::move(object); object = X(...);` should be valid and do the expected thing.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for the link. It seems to answer my question.

Comment: @Ayrosa OK.  I've closed it as a dupe

Comment: @Ayrosa An example: suppose you have a class with the invariant that the `Data* data` member is not null. In your assignment operator, you write `*data = *rhs.data;`, which is safe because `data` is not null. However, if in your move assignment operator, you the proceeded to write `rhs.data = nullptr;`, you have set `rhs` to a non-assignable state, because `rhs = /* some value */` will dereference the null pointer.

Comment: @Justin I'm assuming that when the author says "leave the object in a destructible state", he means `Data* data = nullptr;`. Then, according to your comment above you can't have both (destructible and assignable state), which is exactly the opposite of what the author is saying.

Comment: @Ayrosa No, you can have both. Some examples on how to do so: instead of `rhs.data = nullptr;`, you could write `rhs.data = new Data;`. Instead of `*data = *rhs.data;`, you could write `if (data && rhs.data) *data = *rhs.data;` and forgo the invariant. There are other viable options as well.