# How to concatenate/merge vectors

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to figure out a way to merge 2 vectors and an integer into one vector. ie

```
return data.push_back(fn(data1), mid, fn(data2));
```

NB This is a recursive function.  The vector data has values stored in it before it reaches the return statement.  I need the values in data to be updated with the values in the return statement.

I have absolutely no idea how to go about doing this.  I've been searching for a couple of hours, but nothing seems to work!

Any guidance is very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered first pushing back all the items (using a loop) from fn(data1), then mid, then all the items from fn(data2)?

Comment: What do you mean by "updated" - change some existing values or just add all values from `data1`, `data2` and `mid` into `data`?

Comment: @Cameron - it's even better to use `insert`, instead of a loop with `push_back` - it's more effective, less code, better style.

Comment: @Cameron - I thought about push back, but fn(data1) is not just 1 value.  It is a call to the same function.  Eventually it will just return 1 single value.

Comment: @Sandra - "eventually?" You mean, it may throw or what? And can it return more than one element?

Comment: @KirilKirov - I mean that I want to basically discard the old values in the data vector, and instead store the values which will come from the following recursive function calls.

Comment: @KirilKirov - What I mean is, it will get to a base case and the recursive calls will stop.  Similar to a recursive fibonacci function.  At this point, it will only return 1 element.  Prior to reaching this base case, there will be multiple elements in both data1 and data2 vectors.

Comment: @Sandra - could you post the source of `fn`? Or it's too long?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`std::vector::insert()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/insert/) accepts an iterator range:

```
std::vector<int> left(fn(data1));
std::vector<int> right(fn(data2));
data.insert(data.end(), left.begin(), left.end());
data.push_back(mid);
data.insert(data.end(), right.begin(), right.end());
return data;
```

You can also use [`std::copy()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/) from `<algorithm>` and [`std::back_inserter()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/back_inserter/) from `<iterator>`:

```
std::copy(left.begin(), left.end(), std::back_inserter(data));
data.push_back(mid);
std::copy(right.begin(), right.end(), std::back_inserter(data));
```

However, `insert()` can know the size of its input range in advance and `reserve()` the appropriate amount of memory, while `back_insert_iterator` is opaque—it just repeatedly calls `push_back()`. They both run in linear time, but `insert()` will probably make fewer allocations.

If the elements of your vectors are more efficient to move than to copy, you can use the C++11 [`std::make_move_iterator()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/make_move_iterator) from `<iterator>` to adapt the input ranges:

```
data.insert(data.end(),
    std::make_move_iterator(left.begin()),
    std::make_move_iterator(left.end()));
data.push_back(mid);
data.insert(data.end(),
    std::make_move_iterator(right.begin()),
    std::make_move_iterator(right.end()));
```

Though I doubt this would make a difference for `int`.

Comment: In C++11, consider a `std::move_iterator` on top of this

Comment: Second `data.insert(data.end(), left.begin(), left.end());` in first code block should be `data.insert(data.end(), right.begin(), right.end());`

Comment: @CanBal: Wow. It only took over two years for someone to notice. It was wrong in the third block as well. Fixed!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would the move iterator corrupt the original data? What are the disadvantages of using the `make_move_iterator`?

Comment: @zehelvion: Not “corrupt”, but it would leave the elements of the input vectors in [moved-from](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7028318/246886) state. A possible disadvantage is that the input vectors cannot be `const` if you want to move from them.

Comment: @JonPurdy Thanks! So in other words, corrupt is wrong, possibly mutated (modified) but valid is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::back_inserter` along with `std::copy`.  For example:

```
void foo(vector<int> lhs, vector<int>& rhs)
{
  vector<int> result;
  copy( lhs.begin(), lhs.end(), back_inserter(result));
  copy( rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), back_inserter(result));
  result push_back(42);
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the insert member function that [takes 3 iterator arguments](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/insert/).