# Why element-getters from rvalued-stl-container return lvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, rvalue

I have a code which have to deal with rvalued stl containers. 
My question is:  why member functions which return an element from rvalued-stl-container, like in:

```
vector<int>{1}.front()
```

returns lvalue and not rvalue? Standard specifies that member of rvalue object is rvalue. I know that I can explicitly move returned element with `std::move`.  But what is a logic of having lvalue return type when returned value is clearly rvalue?

If you would use such an expression as an argument of some valuness-overloaded function, wrong overload will be selected and called function would get a lvalue reference (soon to become dangling).

Comment: Simply because there are no rvalue overloads for the memberfunctions, like `T&& front() &&{ return move(front()); }`

Comment: So, than this is STD defect waiting for rvalue-for-this feature to be implemented?

Comment: I dunno if this really counts as a defect in the standard, but you may aswell try a report in the http://isocpp.org mailing lists.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the addition of `outplace_front()` and `outplace_back()` for outbound rvalues would be better names in the spirit of  `emplace_front()` and `emplace_back()` for inbound rvalues.

Comment: Huh? `front() &&` would `move` the element, it wouldn't remove it.

Comment: @ecatmur and the element count of vector would have to be decreased, right?

Comment: @DeadMG what semantics would outbound rvalue moves have on containers?

Comment: @rhalbersma - element can be moved out from container, but it does not have to be removed from it. It just have to be left in destructible state.

Comment: @LeonidVolnitsky how would that not break a container's invariants? an iterator pointing to a moved out element can no longer be safely derefenced.

Comment: You won't be able to use rvalued container after next sequence point - it will be destructed.

Comment: @rhalbersma sure it can; the moved out element is in an *unspecified but valid state*.

Comment: @ecatmur OK, I realize that now, but still, it is extremely confusing and that behavior should be made explicit through named functions, not through an overload.

Comment: It might seem a little odd, but since the container is an xvalue you're hardly likely to be able to observe what happened to the original element anyway, unless you're doing some pretty hairy stuff.

Comment: @rhalbersma I realize, I should rather bookmark this http://stackoverflow.com/q/7027523/743214 ;)

Comment: This wouldn't add much, since `c.outplace_front()` is equivalent to `std::move(c.front())`.  And it's not actually a counterpart to `emplace_front`, which constructs the element from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Once the compiler has decided to call a particular member function (`int &std::vector<int>::front()`, say) the type system only knows that an `int &` is returned, so it has to treat that as an lvalue even though its lifetime is limited to that of the owner temporary.

Before C++11 it was not possible for a member function to be overloaded according to the value category of the object it is being called on (see [What is "rvalue reference for *this"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610571/what-is-rvalue-reference-for-this)), only on cv-qualification of the object; and a non-const temporary is clearly not `const` so the non-`const` overloads must be available.

As well as the potentially dangling lvalue references you've identified, this led in C++03 to the situation where `operator<<` on a temporary `ostream` could be called with a `char` (member function operator) but not with a `string` (free operator); C++11 fixes this with free operator overloads for rvalue references and rvalue `*this` overload for member functions.

Rvalue `*this` allows three overloads for `front`:

```
T &front() & { return data_[0]; }
const T &front() const & { return data_[0]; }
T &&front() && { return std::move(data_[0]); }
```

The different function body for the rvalue overload is a bit of a wart; this is because the ref-qualifier has no effect on member of `*this` access within the body of a member function.

Comment: That proposal was accepted and is a part of C++11. Clang supports it now, most of the other compilers do not.