# C++11 move and reassigning

Tags: c++, c++11

This code does compile but I'm just beginning studying C++11 and I can't understand what's happening here behind the scenes.

```
void func(int&& var)
{
    int var2(var);
}

void main()
{

    int var1 = 22;
    func(move(var1));
}
```

My guess: move(var1) returns a r-value of var1 (probably its data) and the func function is initializing var2 with the r-value of var1. But why is var1 still valid after the func call? Shouldn't it have an invalid value because its temp value has been re-assigned to var2?

Comment: moving from an `int` is just a copy

Comment: The `std::move` function have to keep the argument valid. This means that it's not required to actually move all types. Basic types, like `int`, will not actually be moved as that would leave them invalid.

Comment: Although int will be a copy as mentioned in answers I believe that the way the type is moved is not proper. int&& var is the reference to rvalue (casted with std::move) however var (by name) is like a lvalue(as you can refer it now by name) and `int var2(var);` would anyway not move the var to var2 and it will be COPY (will call copy constructor). The correct way to `attempt` a move would be int 'var2(std::move(var));'

Comment: **`int`** `main`, and drop the `using namespace std;`, it will make code clearer :)

Comment: *Shouldn't it have an invalid value because its temp value has been re-assigned to var2?* No, the standard requires that objects moved from are in a **valid** undetermined state (i.e. it does not mandate what the state is, but it must be valid)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What can I do with a moved-from object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027523/what-can-i-do-with-a-moved-from-object)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several issues here.

One is that you're working with an `int`. And for an `int` a copy is just as fast as a move. So it's perfectly reasonable for a move to be implemented as a copy.

There is no requirement that move construction (or assignment) alter the value of the thing being moved from. It's a logical error in your code to continue to treat it as if it had a useful value, but it's not required that the value become useless.

The second is that your code as written doesn't actually move anything.  Simply using `::std::move` does not result in something being moved. It's just a nice way to turn an lvalue into an rvalue so that something *can* be moved. In your case, `var` has a name, so it's an lvalue. Your initialization of `var2` in `func` is actually a copy, not a move. If you had written it `int var2(move(var));` it would then be a move and `var1` in `main` would be potentially invalidated at that point.

To reiterate, the `::std::move` function is just there to signal to people reading your code that a move may happen and that the value of the variable after that cannot be counted on. It doesn't actually move anything.

Here is a marked up version of your code:

```
// func requires a temporary argument, something that can be moved from
void func(int&& var)
{
    int var2(var); // Doesn't actually call int(int &&), calls int(int &)
    // int var2(move(var));  // Would actually call int(int &&) and a move would
                             // happen then at this point and potentially alter the
                             // value of what var is referencing (which is var1
                             // in this code).
}

void main()
{
    int var1 = 22;
    func(move(var1)); // Tell people that var1's value may be unspecified after
                      // Also, turn var1 into a temporary to satisfy func's
                      // signature.
}
```

Since your code, as written, does not result in any moves happening, here is a version that does definitely move something somewhere:

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

using ::std;

// Still require an rvalue (aka a temporary) argument.
void func(vector<int>&& var)
{
   // But, of course, inside the function var has a name, and is thus an lvalue.
   // So use ::std::move again to turn it into an rvalue.
   vector<int> var2(move(var));
   // Poof, now whetever var was referencing no longer has the value it used to.
   // Whatever value it had has been moved into var2.
}

int main()
{
   vector<int> var1 = { 32, 23, 66, 12 };
   func(move(var1)); // After this call, var1's value may no longer be useful.
   // And, in fact, with this code, it will likely end up being an empty
   // vector<int>.
}
```

And, of course, this way of writing it is silly. There are sometimes reasons to specify that an argument be a temporary. And that's usually if you have one version of a function that takes a reference, and another that takes an rvalue reference. But generally you don't do that. So, here's the idiomatic way to write this code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

using ::std;

// You just want a local variable that you can mess with without altering the
// value in the caller. If the caller wants to move, that should be the caller's
// choice, not yours.
void func(vector<int> var)
{
   // You could create var2 here and move var into it, but since var is a
   // local variable already, why bother?
}

int main()
{
   vector<int> var1 = { 32, 23, 66, 12 };
   func(move(var1));  // The move now does actually happen right here when
                      // constructing the argument to func and var1's value
                      // will change.
}
```

Of course, giving a name to `var1` in that code is kind of silly. Really, it should just be written this way:

```
   func(vector<int>{ {32, 23, 66, 12} });
```

Then you're just constructing a temporary vector right there and passing it into `func`. No explicit use of `move` required.

Comment: There is, indeed, no requirement that a move constructor invalidate the thing being moved from. In fact, it's just the opposite: the object has to remain valid, so that it can, at least, be destroyed. That is to say, "valid" is a vague term here, and reasoning about its consequences is meaningless until it's been clearly defined.

Comment: @PeteBecker: I should've used a better word. I've fixed that. You're right, it doesn't 'invalidate' the value. It's just that the value is no longer necessarily anything useful. The only operation that you are promised will work is destruction.

Comment: I wasn't actually disagreeing with the way you said it; this is the tip of a large discussion in the standards committee about what guarantees you have when an object has been moved from. I mentioned it to raise awareness of the underlying issue: an object's move constructor has to at least ensure that the moved from object can be destroyed, and in the case of the C++ library types, member functions that have no preconditions must still work sensibly. For user-defined types, obviously destructibility is critical, and anything else is whatever the design requires.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing to be moved from an int hence a copy is created. For the types that have move constructor or move assignment operator has specific purpose of moving the underlying resources, then there is a change other wise it is a copy.

The std::move will cast an lvalue to  a rvalue so that some resources(objects on heap or file handles) can be moved out to other object however the actual movement happens in move constructor or move assignment operator.

For example consider vector in standard library which has move copy constructor and move assignment operator that does some explicit work to move resources across.

Having said this I believe that the way the type is moved inside function `func`is not proper way to attempt a move. `int&& var` is the reference to rvalue (casted with std::move) however `var`  (by name) is like a lvalue and `int var2(var);` would anyway not move the var to var2 and it will be COPY. The correct way to attempt a move would be `int var2(std::move(var));` I mean if a type has move constructor which can move the resources you will have to use like that.

```
void func(int&& var) //2. Var is a reference to rvalue however the by name the var is a lvalue and if passed as it would invoke copy constructor.
{
    int var2(std::move(var)); // 3. hence to invoke move constructor if it exists the correct attempt would be to case it to rvalue again as move constructors take rvalue. If the move constructor does not exists then copy is called. 
}

void main()
{

    int var1 = 22;
    func(move(var1)); //1. Cast the type to rvalue so that it can be passed to a move copy contructor or move assigment operator. 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The expression `var1` is an lvalue. Applying `std::move(var1)` gives you an rvalue referring to the same object. You then bind this rvalue to the `int&&` called `var`.

The expression `var` is also an lvalue. This is because any expression which is a named variable is an lvalue (even if its type is an rvalue reference). You then initialise `var2` with the value of `var`.

So all you've done is copied the value from `var1` to `var2`. Nothing has been moved at all. In fact, you cannot even move from a fundamental type like an `int`. Attempting to initialise or assign from a temporary `int` will just copy its value and not move anything.

Even if you were using a type `T` that had a move constructor and assignment operator, your code wouldn't move anything. That's because the only non-reference initialisation you do is the line `int var2(var);`, but here `var` is an lvalue. That means the copy constructor will be used instead.

The simplest way to move from `var1` to `var2` would be to do this:

```
void func(T var)
{
    T var2(move(var));
}

void main()
{

    T var1(22);
    func(move(var1));
}
```

This will move from `var1` to create `var` and then it will move from `var` to create `var2`.

You *could* do this in almost the same way, except change `var` back to an rvalue reference, but I don't recommend it. You would have to document that the rvalue being passed will be invalidated by the internal moving.

Answer (score 1):

> move(var1) returns a r-value of var1 (probably its data)

No, `move(var1)` returns an rvalue reference, referring to `var1`.

> and the func function is initializing var2 with the r-value of var1

`func` copies `var1` to `var2`. If `var1` were of a type with a move constructor, then the move constructor would be called to initialize `var2`. But it is not.

> But why is var1 still valid after the func call?

Because copying an `int` doesn't make it invalid.

> Shouldn't it have an invalid value?

There's no special "invalid value" of `int`. Using an uninitialized object has undefined behavior, but this object is not uninitialized.

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, your example uses a primitive type, which in essence invokes a copy, because a move just simply cannot occur here.  However, I've created an example where a move can occur, using `std::string`.  Its guts can be moved out from under, and you can see in this example that is what happens.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<utility>

void func(std::string&& var)
{
    // var is an lvalue, so call std::move on it to make it an rvalue to invoke move ctor
    std::string var2(std::move(var));
    std::cout << "var2: " << var2 << std::endl;
}

int main()
{

    std::string var1 = "Tony";
    std::cout << "before call: " << var1 << std::endl;
    func(std::move(var1));
    std::cout << "after call: "  << var1 << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
before call: Tony
var2: Tony
after call:
```

You can see that `var1` has indeed been moved from and it no longer contains any data, however it is only in an *unspecified* state per the Standard and is still reusable.

[Live Example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/QHaXl%2410)