# What is the usage of std::forward in parameter passing?

Tags: c++, c++11, forward, perfect-forwarding

See the piece of code below(notice that s is a array with char instead of string):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

void func(std::string & s, char a) {
  std::cout << "here1" << std::endl;
  // ...
}

void func(std::string && s, char a) {
  std::cout << "here2" << std::endl;
  // ...
}

template <class T>
void foo(T && s) {
  std::cout << "foo2" << std::endl;
  func(s, ':');
  //func(std::forward<T>(s), ':');
}

int main(int agrc, char *argv[])
{
  //std::string s("a:b:c:d");
  char s[8] = "abcdefg";
  foo(std::move(s));
  std::string s2("abcd")
  foo(s2);
  return 0;  
}
```

If I replace `func(s, ':')` using `std::forward`, it makes no difference, the foo function will do the prefect forwarding without `std::forward` in this case.

Is there mis-understanding of 'prefect forwarding' with `std::forward` in C++11?

Comment: Note that you shouldn't be using `s` after it's been moved from.

Comment: [Both of the calls print `here1` for me](http://ideone.com/LE3qrQ). And with `std::forward` I get `here2` then `here1`, just as expected.

Comment: @chris I disagree. The state of the object would be undefined, but still valid (especially `operator=`) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027523/what-can-i-do-with-a-moved-from-object

Comment: @pmr, Good point, but better safe than something bad happening later.

Comment: your update is calling `foo(char* &&)` and `func(std::string &&)` due to implicit constructor of `std::string`.

Comment: Passing an array of `char`, which decays into `char*`, which then creates a temporary `string`, really complicates/messes up everything, completely masking the issue you are actually trying to test.

Comment: Why do you call the array `s`? When you have functions taking a `string` called `s`? That's really confusing. The moment you had to write a notice pointing this confusion out to us, you should have changed your mind and renamed the array `ar`!

Comment: @chris: Where is the string moved from?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, It's irrelevant now. It used to be moved and then passed with just `s` instead of `s2` existing.

Comment: @chris: Even in that version, I see no move. You know `std::move` doesn't perform any move, right?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, Yeah, I know, which makes it even sadder. You win.

Comment: @chris: It was such a bad name choice :(

Answer (score 5):

It makes a difference. In your case `func(s, ':')` will only ever call the overload of `func` that takes reference to a `std::string`.

The issue is that named variables and parameters are lvalues themselves and this is also the reason why `std::forward` exists in the first place.

In your example it has the appearance that the right overload is chosen for the first call to `foo` even if you don't use `std::forward`. This is just because you actually call `foo` with a `char[]` argument which is used to implicitly construct a temporary of `std::string`.

Comment: @xunzhang Your example is bad. Because in the first case `foo` uses an array type and constructs a temporary at the call site. This is why you believe the right overload is chosen. I fixed your example: http://ideone.com/btZd7Y

Answer (score 1):

Lets consider first case `foo(std::move(s))`. Inside of `foo`, `s` will be bind to rvalue. But since it has a name (`s`) it's not an rvalue anymore. So when you pass `s` to `func` it will be like passing lvalue to it - it will trigger `here1` version. But if you will pass `s` via `std::forward` it will be rvalue once again.

In second case `s` is lvalue reference when foo is entered, so it doesn't change anything whether you pass it directly or via `std::forward`. You would need to use `std::move` to get rvalue out of `s` again.