# What kind of optimizations does rvalue guarantee?

Tags: c++, c++11, optimization, rvalue

I want to construct an object with another using rvalue.

```
class BigDataClass{
public:
    BigDataClass(); //some default BigData
    BigDataClass(BigDataClass&& anotherBigData);
private:
    BigDataClass(BigDataClass& anotherBigData);

    BigDataPtr m_data;
};
```

So now I want to do something like:

```
BigDataClass someData;
BigDataClass anotherData(std::move(someData));
```

So now anotherData gets rValue. It's an eXpiring Value in fact, so as [http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move%20cppreference) states compiler now
has an oppourtunity to optimize the initialization of anotherData with moving
someData to another.

In my opinion we can in fact get 2 different things:

1. Optimized approach: data moved. It's optimized, fast and we're happy
2. Nonoptimized approach: data not moved. We have to copy data from object to another AND delete data from the first one(as far as I know after changing object to rvalue once we cannot use it, because it has got no ownership of data, that it held). In fact it can be even slower than initialization with lvalue referrence due to deletion operation.

Can we really get so unoptimized way of data initialization?

Comment: if the new object is supposed to take ownership then usually there's nothing left to free for the old one (its pointers should be nulled out) - the only overhead is executing a deconstructor

Comment: I don't understand the "can get 2 different things" part. You write the class, you decide. If **you** don't optimize the move, but copy every member, then you've created a legal but inefficient "move" constructor. The rules only say that a move constructor must leave the source in a destructable state; leaving the source untouched is therefore valid.

Comment: that's what I got in a wrong way

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You said:

> So now anotherData gets rValue. It's an eXpiring Value in fact, so as http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move states **compiler** now has an oppourtunity to optimize the initialization of anotherData with moving someData to another.

Actually, what it stated was:

> **Code** that receives such an xvalue has the opportunity to optimize away unnecessary overhead by moving data out of the argument, leaving it in a valid but unspecified state.

That is, it's the code that's responsible for optimization here, not the compiler. All `std::move(someData)` does is cast its argument to an rvalue reference. Given that `BigDataClass` has a constructor that takes an rvalue reference, that constructor is preferred, and that constructor *will* be the one that is called. There isn't any room for change here from the compiler's point of view. Thus the code will do whatever the `BigDataClass(BigDataClass&&)` constructor does.

Comment: It's a stupid quote, because **code** doesn't "do" anything.

Comment: I quite understand it now. Thank you.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit rephrased (mostly by removing in favor of the extended discussion in Notes)

Comment: _"That is, it's the code that's responsible for optimization here"_ still makes no sense I'm afraid

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you are confused with what is optimization and what is not. Using move constructor (when available) is not an optimization, it is mandated by standard. It is not that the compiler has this opportunity, it has to do this.
On the other hand, copy elision is an optimization which compiler has an opportunity to perform. How relibale it is, depends on your compiler (though they are applying it pretty uniformely) and the actual function code.

Answer (score 1):

You think about what the optimizer can do with move semantics. Simply nothing itself! You, the coder, has to implement the code which is the optimization compared against the constructor with a const ref.

The question can go to the opposite:
If the compiler already knows that you have a rvalue which is passed as const ref to a constructor, the compiler is able to do the construction as if the value is generated in the constructor itself. Copy eliding is done very often by up to date compilers. The question here is ( for me ) how many effort I should spend to write some rvalue reference constructions to get the same result as the compiler already builds on the fly for me.

OK, in c++11 you have a lot of opportunities to handle code for forwarding and moving by your algorithms. And yes, some benefit can be generated. But I see the benefit only for templated code where I have the need to move/forward some of the parameters to (meta)template functions.

And on the opposite: Handling rvalue references must taken with care and the meaning of a valid but undefined state rise some questions on every user who use your interface implementation. See also: [What can I do with a moved-from object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027523/what-can-i-do-with-a-moved-from-object)

> What kind of optimizations does rvalue guarantee

Simply nothing. You have to implement it!

Comment: it's very well explained. Thank you very much :)