# Why is it a good idea for (C++) types to be regular?

Tags: c++, types, idioms, regular-type

(This question stems for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56085280/why-is-rangesostream-iterator-default-constructible) more specific questions about stream iterators.)

A type is [said](http://elementsofprogramming.com/eop-concepts.pdf) [Stepanov, McJones] to be **Regular** if:

- it is equality-comparable
- it is assignable (from other values of the type)
- it is destructible
- it is default-constructible (i.e. constructible with no arguments)
- It has a (default) total ordering of its values

(and there's some wording about "underlying type" which I didn't quite get.)

Some/many people claim that, when designing types - e.g. for the standard library of C++ - it is worthwhile or even important to make an effort to make these types regular, possibly ignoring the total-order requirement. Some mention the maxim:

> Do as the `int`s do.

and indeed, the `int` type satisfies all these requirements. However, default-constructible types, when constructed, hold some kind of null, invalid or junk value - `int`s do. A different approach is requiring initialization on construction (and de-initialization on destruction), so that the object's lifetime corresponds to its time of viability.

To contrast these two approaches, one can perhaps think about a T-pointer type, and a T-reference or T-reference-wrapper type. The pointer is basically regular (the ordering assumes a linear address space), and has `nullptr` which one needs to look out for; the reference is, under the hood, a pointer - but you can't just construct a reference-to-nothing or a junk-reference. Now, pointers may have their place, but we mostly like to work with references (or possibly reference wrappers which are assignable).

So, why should we prefer designing (as library authors) and using regular types? Or at least, why should we prefer them in so many contexts?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking why default initialized objects should hold junk data? I don't think anyone claimed that. In fact, most objects in the standard library have a well defined default value (`std::vector`, `std::string`, all other containers except for `std::array`).

Comment: @Ayxan: No, that's not what I meant. See edit of the last sentence. Also, your first two examples are worth discussing: `std::vector` is very meaningfully default-constructed because it has a "legitimate" empty state. This is sorta-kinda the case for `std::string`; although personally I would disallow a default constructor for a string class: You want a string? Say what it contains. If you want an empty string, say so; as a string is not quite like a sequence of characters you insert into.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is the most significant answer, but you could make the argument that "no uninitialized state" / "no junk value" is a principle that doesn't sit well with move-assignment: After you move from your value, and take its resources away - what state does it remain in? It is not very far from default-constructing it (unless the move-assignment is based on some sort of swapping; but then - you could look at move construction).

The rebuttal would be: "Fine, so let's not have such types move-assignable, only move-destructible"; unfortunately - C++ decided sometime in the 2000's to go with non-destructive moves. See also this question & answer by @HowardHinnant:

[Why does C++ move semantics leave the source constructed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33455067/why-does-c-move-semantics-leave-the-source-constructed)