# C++ move constructor for an owning pointer member

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I'm asking something that looks trivial but I had problems with. Let's assume, for the sake of explanation, a structure like this one:

```
class MyClass{
    int* m_Number;
public:
    int value() const {return *m_Number;}
    void setValue(int val){*m_Number=val;}
    MyClass() : m_Number(new int(3)){}
    ~MyClass() {if(m_Number) delete m_Number;}
    MyClass(const MyClass& other):m_Number(new int(*other.m_Number)){}
    MyClass& operator=(const MyClass& other){if(m_Number) *m_Number=*other.m_Number; else m_Number=new int(*other.m_Number); return *this;}
    MyClass& operator=(MyClass&& other){std::swap(m_Number,other.m_Number); return *this;}
    MyClass(MyClass&& other){
            //????
    }
}
```

What should I put in there?
My options are:

1)

```
    MyClass(MyClass&& other)
            :m_Number(other.m_Number)
    {
            other.m_Number=nullptr;
    }
```

But then the moved from object is not in a valid state. calling value() should return something valid but undetermined while here I just segfault. I could check m_Number in value() and setValue() but you realise it's a huge drag in real code.

---

2)

```
    MyClass(MyClass&& other)
            :m_Number(other.m_Number)
    {
            other.m_Number= new int(3);
    }
```

But a move constructor that can throw is a no go (or at least as I understand it) and it's also a drag of the performance enhancement, in fact this code is equal or worse that the copy constructor.

What do you think?

Did I miss something?

Is there a preferred way to go?

Thanks in advance

Edit: This question received an answer from the convener of the std committee and it fundamentally disagrees with the answers to this post. You can find it in this article https://herbsutter.com/2020/02/17/move-simply/

Comment: `other` is supposed to be a temporary. It usually is not possible to call `value()` on it because it disappeared. You cannot expect functions to work on a moved from object besides assigning a new value. The proper fix is to leave the class as is and fix whoever is using a moved-from object inappropriately.

Comment: In #1, why does it matter that the moved-from object is in an invalid state - if you're calling the move constructor, doesn't that mean that the moved-from object is about to be destroyed anyway?

Comment: As long as the destructor works in the moved-from state (it does, and you don’t even need the null check because `delete` is safe on a null pointer), that should be good enough.

Comment: @BenS. no, not necessarily

Comment: Is there really a difference between #2 and not supporting move construction at all? You are essentially implementing another copy constructor.

Comment: Option #1 is fine, you just need to document what operations are valid on the moved-from object. It's perfectly acceptable to say "the only valid operation on a moved-from object is destruction, other operations cause undefined behavior." Then you don't check anything, and if the user invokes `value()` or `setValue()` on a moved-from object, they get UB from the null pointer dereference -- just like you told them.

Comment: I refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7028318/4124855) by the guy that put move semantic in the standard in the first place. In the linked video he's even more specific saying that "any function that does not require a precondition can be validly executed by a moved from object" citing std::vector<T>::size as an example hence my doubt here

Comment: @IlBeldus But he's talking about stuff *in the standard library.* Your class is *not* in the standard library -- you can make the rules. Or, to put it another way, specify that the precondition for `value()` and `setValue()` is "this object hasn't been used to move-construct or move-assign another object." Problem solved. Now if they call `value()` or `setValue()` on a moved-from object, they have violated the precondition.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your support.
I'm a lot more confident in my leave-it-null solution

Comment: @cdhowie It’s probably a good idea to at least implement an `isValid` method which just returns whether `m_Number == nullptr`. Then the precondition to all the methods is `isValid()`, and if you might obtain a moved-from object which isn’t immediately destructed (which is possible without UB) you can check to make sure.

Comment: @DanielH I don't disagree that one could add such a method, however... *"if you might obtain a moved-from object which isn’t immediately destructed (which is possible without UB)"* -- If you're passing around a moved-from object that says that moved-from objects have no use, that's a pretty clear bug. Of course you can obtain one, but if code does anything with a moved-from object other than allowing it to be destroyed, that's simply misuse of the class.

Comment: @cdhowie Actually it's totally safe to assign (copy or move assign) to a moved from object in the example above and since my code ends up in a library I don't want to introduce a behaviour the average programmer would not find intuitive by default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, there's no reason to use `new` and `delete` here, you should be using `make_unique<int>` to create the object and a `unique_ptr<int>` to manage it automatically. But that doesn't solve your problem, of what the move constructor can do. There are some other options in addition to the two you suggest:

3) don't give it a move constructor, just leave it as copyable

4) document that calling `value` or `setValue` on a moved-from object is not allowed, and leave the moved-from object with a null pointer. Depending where moves happen in your program that might be fine. If moved-from objects are never accessed, everything just works.

4a) As above, but add sanity checks in case it does ever happen:

```
int value() const {
  assert(m_Number != nullptr);
  return *m_Number;
}
```

or:

```
int value() const {
  if (m_Number == nullptr)
    throw std::logic_error("accessed a moved-from object");
  return *m_Number;
}
```

5) Add checks to `setValue` to re-initialize the object with a new `int` if it's currently null, and make `value` return some default value:

```
int value() const { return m_Number ? *m_Number : 0; }

void setValue(int val) {
  if (!m_Number)
    m_Number = new int(val);
  else
    *m_Number = val;
}
```

Comment: 4a1 is what I'm currently doing

Answer (score 1):

You are dereferencing your pointer in the `.value()` call. You will always segfault in the event that `m_Number` is invalid.

Your first solution to the move constructor is correct, you should set the 'other' object to a default state. To solve this, you could make your `.value()` method throw, or return a default value in the event of non-existent resource.

Your destructor already accounts for the null case, so make sure the rest of it accounts for it as well.

Comment: More context: imagine m_Number actually being a [pimpl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) of a class with many methods all accessing it. adding a check in every one of them is 1) expensive in terms of performance 2) quite a lot of boring work

Answer (score 0):

1. Your first approach is probably the best if modifying `MyClass` such that `m_Number = nullptr` is a valid state is reasonable to do (and would be best practice if it were the default state too). I'd argue if having no-heap memory associated with `MyClass` is not a valid state, you should be allocating it inside of a `std::unique_ptr`, and passing around a raw pointer to that instead of implementing a move constructor.
2. If `1.` is not an option, this is a reasonable way to go. While there certainly is a performance hit for allocating un-needed memory, it is quite minor, especially considering you are constructing a class as part of this operation (which itself requires memory). If its a small chunk of memory that is needed as in your example, the memory allocator will likely draw it from its own pool without the need of a system call. If it is a large chunk of memory (as I would expect since you're implementing move semantics), then on most modern operating systems it will be a lazy allocation (so it would still be better than a copy constructor).

Comment: Option 2. seems to make the move constructor identical to the copy constructor in performance terms. That performance hit might not be significant, but why bother implementing a move constructor at all if it is no faster than a copy?

Answer (score -2):

Do not use raw owning pointers, convert your class to use `std::unique_ptr`, and all your problems will go away.

Comment: Except that it will still leave an invalid object after a move.

Comment: There are often reasons to not use the provided library pointers. This looks like a simplified example; of course there are better options than the simplified example (such as using a literal `3`), but the question is about move semantics in general.

Comment: I do not understand the problem. Yes, moved from object is in valid, but undefined state. What is the actual question here?

Comment: @JonathanWakely Isn't that standard behavior for *any* object that has been moved from?

Comment: Turning m_Number into std::unique_ptr<int> and removing the destructor holds the same result. It's kinda not about ownership here.

Comment: @0x5453 no, absolutely not. Most objects are still valid after moving from them, e.g. you can still use a `std::string` after moving from it (it's just empty). In the OP's code calling `value()` would be undefined behaviour after a move.

Comment: @SergeyA _"moved from object is in valid, but undefined state"_ what does that mean? The OP considers a valid object to be one that you can call `value()` on, so if its pointer is null it's not valid (and it's not "undefined" either, its state is known precisely, it's just not usable as a valid `MyClass`). Using `unique_ptr` is certainly better than manual memory management, but it doesn't answer the OP's question.