# Object passed to std::move but not moved from?

Tags: c++, c++11, undefined-behavior, rvalue-reference

I am reviewing some code like this, where `A` is a moveable type:

```
// Returns true exactly when ownership of a is taken
bool MaybeConsume(A&& a) {
  if (some condition) {
    Consume(std::move(a));  // ???
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

// ... elsewhere ...

A a;
if (!MaybeConsume(std::move(a))) {
  a.DoSomething();  // !!!
}
```

Our static analysis tool complains that `a` is used after being moved (at `!!!`). IIUC `std::move` is only a `static_cast`, and the object `a` won't actually get gutted until a move constructor or assignment operator is called (presumably in `Consume`). Assuming `MaybeConsume` satisfies the contract in the comment,

1. Does this work?
2. Is it UB?
3. Is `std::move` at `???` a no-op?

(Probably this particular instance can be refactored to avoid the subtlety, but I would still like to ask for my own understanding).

Comment: Note - I would consider changing it to `MaybeConsume(A& a)` just to make it less confusing.

Comment: at the end of  "if (!MaybeConsume(std::move(a))) {", ownership of the object a has been  transferred to function MaybeSonsume, and is never returned back.

Comment: @JohnZ.Li No, transfer of ownership is dependent on *some condition* being true

Comment: make it std::tuple<A&&, bool> MaybeConsume(A&&, a),  always transfer the object back, having a bool value indicating whether the object has been consumed.

Comment: @JohnZ.Li That is why I'm conceptually troubled by `!!!`, but my understanding is that `std::move(a)` by itself doesn't modify `a`, so the code still works (at least in practice, possibly not according to standard). eg see http://cpp.sh/8yuim

Comment: @JohnZ.Li You have strange ideas about how rvalue references and move semantics work. If `MaybeConsume` is indeed unconditionally assuming ownership of its argument, how would returning an rvalue reference, wrapped in a `tuple` or otherwise, transfer ownership back to the caller?

Comment: @Praetorian The comment is just a hint, one must first capture the returned tuple of course. it is obvious that the if() clause should be modified.

Comment: @JohnZ.Li And what is *capturing the returned tuple*? Would you return an lvalue reference to a function local variable? If no, then why do you think returning an rvalue reference in that case is OK?

Comment: @Praetorian I added a piece of sample code to an answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a spurious warning from your static analysis tool.

> 1. Does this work?

Yes, `MaybeConsume` is doing what the comment says. It's only taking ownership of its argument when `some condition` is true (assuming `Consume` actually does move construct/assign from its argument).

[`std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) is indeed just a fancy `static_cast<T&&>` so `MaybeConsume(std::move(a))` is not transferring ownership, you're simply binding a reference to `MaybeConsume`'s parameter.

> 2. Is it UB?

No, you're not making use of `a` if `MaybeConsume` indicates it has assumed ownership of its argument.

> 3. Is `std::move` at *???* a no-op?

Well, it's a no-op because it's just a `static_cast`, but if you meant to ask whether it's unnecessary, then, no, it isn't. Within the body of `MaybeConsume`, `a` is an lvalue [because it has a name](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_05.html). If the signature of `Consume` is `void Consume(A&&)`, then the code won't compile without that `std::move`.

---

From the example usage you've shown, it seems you're not supposed to call `MaybeConsume` with a prvalue argument, since the caller should presumably use the argument in some other manner if the function returns `false`. If that's true, then you should change its signature to `bool MaybeConsume(A&)`. This will probably make your static analysis tool happy because that would allow you to write `if (!MaybeConsume(a))`.

Comment: On further thought asking about UB was probably on the wrong track; since a moved from object should still be in a "valid but unspecified" state, I guess even using it in that case would not be UB.

Comment: @stewbasic Not quite, *valid but unspecified* is a promise the C++ standard library makes for moved from objects in `std` namespace. It's an excellent guideline to follow for your own types, but there's nothing in the language that enforces that. You can implement a type that dies a horrible death if used in any manner after moving from it if you choose to do so. As far as the standard library goes, you can use a moved from object in any way as long as you [don't violate the preconditions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7028318/241631) for that operation.

Comment: I am pretty sure that a moved-from object has at least to be destructible, and destroying an object certainly counts as "being used".

Answer (score 0):

To understand why the static analysis tool raises a warning, one needs to think in the way a static analyzer does. When it sees a piece of code like below:

```
A a;
fun(std::move(a);
a.method();
```

It is not clear what might happen inside fun() call. To successfully perform method() on a depends some prerequisites being satisfied, that might not( or no longer) holds after call of fun(). While the programmer might well know that it is safe to call method(), the analyzer does not, so it raises a warning.

The following is only my own opinion. It is safer to just assume the ownership of a is wholly taken by fun(). To prevent confusion, it is better to enforce a borrow-and-return style, Thinking of it as if a friend borrows a book from you, you don't (can not) use that book until it is returned. Thus never risk oneself accidentally invoke an object that should be "dead" by then.

See the below demonstration code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>
#include<cassert>
struct A {
public:
    int *p; 
public:
    A() {
        p = new int();
        assert(p != nullptr);
        std::cout << p << std::endl;
        std::cout << "default constrctor is called" << std::endl;
    }
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A& operator=(const A&) = delete;
    A(A&& _a): p(_a.p) {
        _a.p = nullptr;
        std::cout << p << std::endl;
        std::cout << "move constructor is called" << std::endl;;
    }
    A& operator=(A&& _a) {
        std::cout << "move assignment is called"<<std::endl;;
        p = std::move(_a.p);
        return *this;
    }
    void DoSomthing(){
        std::cout << "do somthing is called" << std::endl;
        *p = 100;
        std::cout << "value of p is changed"<<std::endl;
    }
};
std::tuple<A&&, bool>  MaybeConsume(A&& a) {
    if (1==2) {//try 1==1 alternatively
        delete a.p;
        a.p = nullptr;//consume
        std::cout << "content consumed" << std::endl;
        return std::make_tuple(Consume(std::move(a)), true);
    }
    else {
        return std::make_tuple(std::move(a), false);
    }
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    std::tuple<A&&, bool> t = MaybeConsume(std::move(a));
    if (!(std::get<bool> (t))) {
        A a1 = std::move(std::get<A&&>(t));
        a1.DoSomthing();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like your `Consume` function only borrows `a` and returns it afterwards. Could you give an example where `Consume` permanently takes ownership of `a`? eg maybe `A` is `std::unique_ptr<T>` and the object `a` points to is freed in `Consume`.

Comment: Your example is just passing around references to the original `a` in `main`, it's never being moved from. Your comments above said `MaybeConsume` always takes ownership of `a`. That would be like adding `auto a1 = std::move(a);` as the first line within `MaybeConsume` and using `a1` in the remainder of the function. In that case your example would have undefined behavior if you tried to use the reference returned in the `tuple` within `main`. Also, this isn't really an answer. If you're posting an answer, you should explain what it contains.

Comment: @stewbasic see the updated version. if resource owned by a is freed, DoSomething will never be called. still safe.

Comment: Please keep in mind that calling `method()` is always supposed to be valid, as a `move` should always leave the object in a valid state, whatever it may be. An object that is being moved is not being destroyed. In your later example, `DoSomthing` is incorrectly implemented, as `p` being `nullptr` is an actual possibility after an object is being moved. So either you allocate new memory for a moved object, or you add a check in `DoSomthing`. A failure to do so just means that your object is not correctly implemented and not safe, and it violates the assumptions of a `move`.