# C++ move iterator and int vector

Tags: c++, vector, move

I am trying to understand the move iterator. This is the sample code from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/make_move_iterator

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
 
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> s{"one", "two", "three"};
 
    std::vector<std::string> v1(s.begin(), s.end()); // copy
 
    std::vector<std::string> v2(std::make_move_iterator(s.begin()),
                                std::make_move_iterator(s.end())); // move
 
    std::cout << "v1 now holds: ";
    for (auto str : v1)
            std::cout << "\"" << str << "\" ";   //return one, two, three
    std::cout << "\nv2 now holds: ";
    for (auto str : v2)
            std::cout << "\"" << str << "\" ";   //return one, two, three
    std::cout << "\noriginal list now holds: ";
    for (auto str : s)
            std::cout << "\"" << str << "\" ";   //return nothing
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

So the move iterator moves as expected. But when I made some minor changes:

```
    std::vector<int> s{1, 2, 3};
 
    std::vector<int> v1(s.begin(), s.end()); // copy
 
    std::vector<int> v2(std::make_move_iterator(s.begin()),
                                std::make_move_iterator(s.end())); // move
```

s still references {1, 2, 3} despite moving. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: There isn't much point to moving `int`s so a move is pretty much the same as a copy. I also don't recommend trying to use objects after moving from them. The only guarantees you get from a moved-from object is you can safely destroy it. Absolutely no guarantees are given about what it contains.

Comment: Supplemental reading: [What can I do with a moved-from object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027523/what-can-i-do-with-a-moved-from-object)

Answer (score 0):

Those outputs are expected. In the first case, you are moving an `std::string`, which is an object that has a move constructor defined. In the second case, you are moving an `int`, which is just a number and therefore doesn't have a move constructor.

When you move from the `std::string`, your program will take the underlying pointer to a dynamic character array and place that pointer into the new string.

When you move from the `int`, your program won't do anything special because there are no member variables or anything to move around. So really there is no difference between copying and moving an `int`.

Hopefully this makes sense! Leave a comment if you'd like more explanation and I'll try my best to answer :)

Comment: Slight tweak: in  *there is no dynamic memory or anything to move around* the memory doesn't need to be dynamic.

Comment: @user4581301 Good clarification. To explain that quote, I was referencing the fact that `std::string` maintains dynamic memory and pointing out that an `int` differs from `std::string` in that it does not.

Comment: Understood. But another fun fact: There's no guarantee that a `std::string` contains dynamic memory either. [See Short String Optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315041/meaning-of-acronym-sso-in-the-context-of-stdstring)

Comment: Ohhh that's awesome! Thanks for the link, it's a pretty clever concept :O