# Why not destory after calling std::move?

Tags: c++

As seen in the following, I can still print "3" after the code `printf("%d\n", p1.val);`. Isn't the class `p1` destroyed after `std::move`? [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUWVE.png)

The code is here:

```cpp
class pointer
{
public:
    int val;
    int* my_pointer;

    pointer()
    {
        val = 0; 
        my_pointer = new int;
    }
    pointer(pointer&& other)
    {
        val = other.val;
        my_pointer = other.my_pointer;      
        other.my_pointer = nullptr;
    }
    ~pointer()
    {
        delete my_pointer;
        my_pointer = nullptr;
    }
};
int main()
{   
    pointer p1;
    p1.val = 3;
    *p1.my_pointer = 3;
    pointer p2(std::move(p1));
    printf("%d\n", p1.val);
    printf("%d\n", p2.val);
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: It's _undefined behavior_, hence nobody can tell why your code behaves like it does.

Comment: post code as text, not in images

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7028318/402169), which explains how a moved-from object acts. Moving does not destroy the object, it puts it in an unspecified state.

Comment: No, it's not destroyed. "Moving" does not move or destroy anything, and `std::move` is just a cast. All that happens to `p1` is the things that you wrote in the move constructor.

Comment: `p1` is destroyed at the end of the scope where it's defined. Moving from it doesn't change that.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but assigning `nullptr` to `my_pointer` in the destructor doesn't accomplish anything. The object is going away, so there is no valid way to access its `my_pointer` field -- it no longer exists.

Comment: Hmm. I have no idea why this question was closed. It's perfectly clear and detailed enough. What's the problem?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience. It helped me understand the usage of std::move more deeply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So move semantics is basically doing a shallow copy from an element that is about to die (go out of scope).

Say that we have object, `dying_obj`, that we know is about to go out of scope (and hence have its destructor called), we can change its type to an `rvalue` with `std::move` like so:

```c
other_obj = std::move(dying_obj);
```

`std::move` is just a type cast. It has no run-time effect other than how its type is interpreted by the compiler for things like overloaded function resolution. In this case, constructor overloads.

It's important the understand that this really is just a type flag, and the ***convention*** is that it refers to an object out-of-scope for its caller.

BUT.. to hammer the point home that `rvalues` and `lvalues` are just little flags, we could abuse these flags for other purposes (don't ever do this!):

```c
void increment (int & i)
{
    ++i;
}

void increment (int && i)
{
    --i;
}

int main ()
{
    // count up to 10:
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; increment(i))
        std::cout << i << " ";

    // count down from 20:
    for (int i = 20; i > 0; increment(std::move(i)))
        std::cout << i << " ";
}
```

The above code uses an `lvalue` as an "add" type and the `rvalue` as a minus type. Very dumb, but also perfectly logical, it works correctly and with defined behaviour.

Getting back to the real world: when you call a function/method with an `rvalue` object, like `foo(std::move(obj))`, you're signalling to the function that it can do as it likes with that object because it won't be used by the caller any more. That's the ***convention*** for what the signal means, but it's just a signal. You can certainly rely on the STL library to follow this convention everywhere, and probably every single library that's ever used by sane people.

Standard procedure is to do the move copy as efficiently as possible. Sadly we're forced to copy all the values, but we're not forced to copy all of the content that a pointer points to (this is where we do a shallow copy instead). For the pointers, we really must be careful to make sure that the destructor of `dying_obj` won't delete any of its allocations - there's lots of ways to do this, actually, but the simplest is just to change any pointers to `nullptr` after the copy. We could change the other values of `dying_obj`, but we don't need to and it takes time, so it's typical to leave it as it is.

So it's important to understand that the `std::move(obj)` doesn't invoke a destruction of the `obj` - it will still go out of scope at the same place, so at that point its destructor will be called - which, if we've done our job correctly, will have no effect at all.

As for your precise problem:

```c
pointer p1;
p1.val = 3;
*p1.my_pointer = 3;
pointer p2(std::move(p1));
printf("%d\n", p1.val);
printf("%d\n", p2.val);
```

With `std::move(p1)` you're communicating to the constructor that `p1` won't be used again, so it can pull out its contents (do the shallow copy), but then on the next line you show that you're still using `p1`:

```c
printf("%d\n", p1.val);
```

So you're breaking your promise.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I misunderstood the use of std::move. I thought that the moved object will be automatically destroyed and therefore cannot be used.