# c++ reassign after moved

Tags: c++, vector, move

From other posts that I understand after moved from, the object is in a valid, but unspecified state. Can I reassign things to the vector, illustrated by the example below:

```
std::vector a = {1,2,3};
std::vector b = std::move(a);
a = {1,3,4}
```

Does it guarantee that a will contain 1,3,4 after all.

Comment: See [What can I do with a moved from object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7027523). In general, assignment doesn't have preconditions, it can be done with any valid state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is guaranteed. After the move, the [`vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) is guaranteed to be empty, i.e. has no elements. It's fine to be assigned by other contents.

> After the move, `other` is guaranteed to be [`empty()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/empty).

Answer (score 2):

Of course, `a` will contain `{1,3,4}`. Simply moving from a vector means taking its content, the dynamically allocated array, and giving that content to the left-hand side beside somethings. Now the assigning will give new content to the old vector. This is perfectly valid.