# Is there a way to convert std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::string>> to std::vector<std::string> without copying?

Tags: c++

The problem is I have a big `vector` contains big `string` contents fetched from local cache wrapped by `shared_ptr`:

```cpp
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::string>>
```

but one of my library API requires:

```cpp
void forExample(std::vector<std::string>& data);
```

In this library, the data will only be read, there is no modification, no memory operations, just read.

So how can I pass the data correctly without copying the big strings, or any other better recommendations? It's ok to change the library API signature if necessary.

Comment: You can move to strings into the new vector, and then move back after the API call. If the strings are really long it might be worth the extra complication.

Comment: Create a vector of empty strings, of the right final size, and then use std::move or std::swap ina loop to populate it without copying the original string data bytes. Move it back after calling the AOI function.

Comment: @wohlstad Would that even work? Can you move back into an object that's being moved from? The moved from object is in an state where only calling the destructor should have to work right? It doesn't sound like something I would be willing to try. (specialy not in a multithreaded environment)

Comment: What is the reason you have pointers to `std::string` to begin with? What problem was that supposed to solve? Generally, pointers to any kind of container-like object, including strings, should be avoided.

Comment: A side note: if the API only reads the data, why not accept is by a `const &` ?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The data is fetched from local memory cache, which uses a shared_ptr to manage the object lifecycle and avoid copying. It may live a long time in local cache and  using by multi-thread.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude usecase for use pointer of string  is queue for broadcast message. we don't know certain time to destroy a string.

Comment: @PepijnKramer it's OK to reassign a moved-from object according to: [What can I do with a moved-from object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027523/what-can-i-do-with-a-moved-from-object).

Comment: @wohlstad Thanks for looking it up std::swap is a great example that brings comfort to my mind ;)

Comment: _The data is fetched from local memory cache..._ Please add information like this to your question, rather than leaving it buried in a comment.  You can always add a comment saying that you've done it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possible approach you can take :
(Assuming no changes to the vector happen on other threads during looping)

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

// helper overloads to get a string& from input
const std::string& to_string_ref(const std::string& str)
{
    return str;
}

// convert a std::shared_ptr<std::string> to const std::string&
const std::string& to_string_ref(const std::shared_ptr<std::string>& pstr)
{
    return *pstr;
}

class api_t
{
public:

    // you can put in either a std::vector<std::string> or
    // a std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::string>
    template<typename container_t>
    void do_something(const container_t& container) // todo constrain on has .begin(), .end()
    {
        for (const auto& value : container)
        {
            // to_string_ref will select the correct "translation"
            do_something_with_a_string(to_string_ref(value));
        }
    }

private:
    void do_something_with_a_string(const std::string& string)
    {
        std::cout << string << "\n";
    }
};


int main()
{
    api_t api;

    std::vector<std::string> input{"123", "456", "789"};
    api.do_something(input);

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::string>> shared_input
    {
        std::make_shared<std::string>("abc"),
        std::make_shared<std::string>("def"),
        std::make_shared<std::string>("ghi")
    };

    api.do_something(shared_input);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this approach better fits my need. Less args, little change on the library only, and no changes on client code calling this API .

Answer (score 8):

Change the signature from

```
// bad
void forExample(std::vector<std::string>& data);
```

to

```
// better
template <typename IT> 
void forExample(It begin, IT end);
```

A bit more is required to constrain the iterators. However, once you pass iterators rather than a whole container you can write an iterator adaptor that also dereferences the smart pointer when the iterator is dereferenced.

Comment: `void forExample(std::ranges:: view auto rng);` would be more convenient.

Comment: @Red.Wave `std::ranges::range`, rather. Or one of the `..._range` concepts.

Comment: Wouldn't `ranges::range` capture by value? For that you'd need explicit `template` declaration with reference arguments. `ranges::view` on the other hand implies reference semantics with simpler syntax and more generic interface.

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you prefer not to change the existing API, you can move the long strings into a new vector, call the API and then move back.

This might make sense (performance-wise) only if the strings are really long.

**Example:**

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>

void forExample(std::vector<std::string>& data)
{
    for (auto const& d : data)
    {
        std::cout << d << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::string>> v1
                    { std::make_shared<std::string>("aaa"), 
                      std::make_shared<std::string>("bbb"),
                      std::make_shared<std::string>("ccc") };

    std::vector<std::string> v2(v1.size());

    // Move from the original container:
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v1.size(); ++i)
    {
        assert(v1[i]);
        v2[i] = std::move(*v1[i]);
    }

    // Call the API:
    forExample(v2);

    // Move back into the original container:
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v1.size(); ++i)
    {
        assert(v1[i]);
        *v1[i] = std::move(v2[i]);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

**Note:**
After moving from an object it is left in an unspecified but valid state. But according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027523/what-can-i-do-with-a-moved-from-object), you can reassign such an object.

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ndEnnd6v7)

Comment: Would that be ok in multi thread? The copied shared_ptr<string> from local cache may be used by multi thread at the same time.

Comment: After you complete the `move`s to the new container you should be able to read the strings from multiple threads. But in order to give a definitive answer I must see a code example (in a new question, becasue this question should not be modified after getting some answers). Multi-threading issues tend to be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

If we really can't change the interface (e.g. to accept a transform-view), and are unwilling to copy the strings into a vector, then we can move their values into a vector, call the function, and then move them back afterwards.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

// Caller is responsible for preventing concurrent access to r or to
// any of its shared pointers (which must not be null).
template<std::ranges::forward_range R>
void call_with_dereference(R r, std::function<void(std::vector<typename std::ranges::range_value_t<R>::element_type>&)> function)
{
    using element_t = std::ranges::range_value_t<R>::element_type;
    auto v = std::vector<element_t>{};
    v.reserve(std::ranges::size(r));

    // Move elements of r into v
    auto dereference = [](auto& e)->auto& {return *e;};
    auto element_view = r | std::views::transform(dereference);
    std::ranges::move(element_view, std::back_inserter(v));

    // Call the function
    function(v);

    // Now move the elements back
    std::ranges::move(v, element_view.begin());
}
```

#### Demo

We'll need to arrange any necessary locking so that other threads that expect to access the strings through the vector of pointers doesn't do so whilst they are in their moved-from state; none is necessary in this single-threaded program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

void reverse_each(std::vector<std::string>& strings)
{
    std::ranges::for_each(strings,
                          [](auto &s){std::ranges::reverse(s);});
}

int main()
{
    auto const strings = std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::string>>{
        std::make_shared<std::string>("abc"),
        std::make_shared<std::string>("def"),
        std::make_shared<std::string>("xyz"),
    };

    call_with_dereference(strings, reverse_each);

    for (auto const& s: strings) {
        std::cout << *s << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

My English is poor！ give your code.
It's unclear.Forgive me for my poor English.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

void print_strings(const std::vector<std::string> &strs)
{
    for (auto &s : strs)
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::string>> strs;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        strs.push_back(std::make_shared<std::string>(std::to_string(rand())));


    // This is a trick, but it's safe，only copy std:string's internal ptr
    // don't modified fake_strs in your library API
    // std::vector<fake_string> didn't take the ownership. 
    // It just create a shadow memory，and it's temp.
    // Its free will not affect the orignal memory allocation
    typedef std::array<char, sizeof(std::string)> fake_string;
    {
        std::vector<fake_string> fake_strs;

        fake_strs.resize(strs.size());
        for (int i = 0, count = strs.size(); i < count; i++)
            memcpy(&fake_strs[i], &(*strs[i]), sizeof(std::string));

        // just call your libray API
        print_strings(*(std::vector<std::string>*)&fake_strs);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `memcpy(&fake_strs[i], &(*strs[i]), sizeof(std::string));` ehr... no. Even if this would work you now have "shared ownership" of memory dynamically allocated for the string and you get double frees. So no it is not a safe solution. Keep repeating this mantra : "Do not use tricks"

Comment: Also any current C++ code is should not to rely on pointers magic and calls like memcpy. Read this [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines)

Comment: Please read my code carefully! std::vector<fake_string> didn't take the ownership. It just create a shadow memory，and it's temp.  It's free will not affect the orignal memroy allocation.

Comment: You are right you are copying to an array not a string I missed that. However I would still never recommend this kind of code to anyone.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).